# AngularJS: Load base64 image from a file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, amazon-s3, base64

I have a list of images, but every image have a s3 file with his **base64 encoded** inside this file.

***Example of image:***

- **https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sensicityissues/1483573056505-61946**

The problem is that if I did something like this:

```
<img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sensicityissues/1483573056505-61946" />
```

The image is not loaded.

If I want that this works in this way I need to do something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-init="vm.loadImage(image, image.url)">
    <img ng-if="image && image.src" data-ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="60" />
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
self.loadImage = (img, url) => {
    $http.get(`http://cors.io/?${url}`)
      .then(r => (img.src = r.data))
}
```

This is working... Okey... But I have 2 big problems with this:

- CORS problems, that I need to resolve with `http://cors.io/?${url}`. For me is not a good solution because is a slowly way to load all the images and if some day `cors.io` stops working, my webpage neither will work...
- If I load an amout of images with this way, all the base64 encoded strings are in memory and the page will have a several memory problems.

Is there another solution to implement this avoiding these big problems?

*(I can't change how images are saved in s3...)*

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/).  Also, on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html) you can find out the way to load base64 images.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

You can't mix http schema that gives you a non byte response as your src attribute value.

You gonna need to build a backend feature in order to serve you these images to your front end app through your own url.

Comment: yes... But my question is about how to load a base64 encoded file, within an url...

Comment: You are trying to retrive ''data' scheme using 'http'; your browser expects to work with bytes and not base64 data. You need to build a backend feature in order to serve you these images to your front end app through your own url.